# A nicer PixelFormat.ToString output

Tags: c#, winforms, image, system.drawing, pixelformat

The [PixelFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat.aspx) enumeration from the System.Drawing.Imaging namespace has members like *Format32bppArgb* or *Format8bppIndexed*, that are displayed when calling its *ToString* method.

Do you know of a built-in or other method that converts PixelFormat values to strings that are more appropriate for display in a graphic program, like *24 BPP* or *24bpp*?

Comment: I don't know of any existing function, but then the enumration doesn't contain an awful lot of values. I wouldn't bother to much with it and just write it myself.

Comment: I was looking for a list of somewhat "standard" strings for PixelFormat values, that users are used to see in graphic programs, that's why I've asked the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this extension method I quickly threw together:

```
public static string ToFancyString(this PixelFormat format)
{
    switch (format)
    {
        case PixelFormat.Format16bppArgb1555:
            return "16bpp ARGB";
        case PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale:
            return "16bpp Gray";
        case PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555:
            return "16bpp RGB";
        case PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb565:
            return "16bpp RGB";
        case PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed:
            return "1bpp Indexed";
        case PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb:
            return "24bpp RGB";
        case PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb:
            return "32bpp ARGB";
        case PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb:
            return "32bpp Premultiplied ARGB";
        case PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb:
            return "32bpp RGB";
        case PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb:
            return "48bpp RGB";
        case PixelFormat.Format4bppIndexed:
            return "4bpp Indexed";
        case PixelFormat.Format64bppArgb:
            return "64bpp ARGB";
        case PixelFormat.Format64bppPArgb:
            return "64bpp Premultiplied ARGB";
        case PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed:
            return "8bpp Indexed";
        default:
            return format.ToString();
    }
}
```